# Multiple writes in Dynamo DB causing the slowing of the whole process?

Tags: multiprocessing, amazon-dynamodb, serverless

There are multiple EC2 instances in which code basically pulls the data from SQS and do some processing and according to that updates/inserts data into dyanamo db.

As multiple writers are present, each EC2 when saving, must lock the db to write it to prevent loss of data but in my sense also at the same time taking longer to process.
Am I right in thinking so, if yes, is there any way of fast tracking this process?

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate on "prevent loss of data"?

Something's to note which may help you

1. All single item writes to DynamoDB are atomic and ACID compliant.
2. If you need concurrency control you can do so by using either Optimistic Locking with a conditional check [1] or with optimistic locking using versioning [2]
3. It's important to note that locking is done on an item level and not a table level, and with well distributed traffic you should not be seeing an increase in processing time.

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_ConditionCheck.html

[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.OptimisticLocking.html

Comment: Thanks Lee for answering so quickly.
1.By loss of data ,I meant that if 2 machines had to update same item(which is very difficut) , can that lead to loss of data(if it maintains ACID ,this wont be affected i guess, thanks for that)
2. My main question is if one EC2 machine is trying to update any records item and other ec2 machine is updating another records item,will it lock the db and other ec2 machine have to wait for it unlock the resource??

Comment: 1. The item will eventually reflect all updates, and if both processes are updating the same attribute it will become last writer wins.

Comment: 2. You cannot/do not lock the entire database in DynamoDB. You can update as many items as you want concurrently. If your using optimistic locking you only prevent that single item from being updated by a process who does not hold a valid version number.

Comment: Oh great 
That helps a lot in figuring out an issue 
Thanks a ton for your help